# Debian Jessie - Can't boot after install dm crypt + luks - grub error

Tags: debian, luks, dm-crypt

So after following [this tutorial](https://xo.tc/setting-up-full-disk-encryption-on-debian-jessie.html).

Grub fails to load this new Debian installation. I followed that whole tutorial with 1 exception: I setup the 3 partitions all with 3 different passwords. everything was installed in an USB pendrive.

All the installation went well, no errors displayed at all. When asked where to install grub, I choose not to install it in the MBR but on my sdb device, where all the Debian install was made.

I get the following grub error when I try to boot into this usb:

> File /grub/i386-pc/normal.mod not found
>
> Grub Rescue:

What can I do to fix this? I tried to search like crazy for a tutorial on how to fix grub in a dm crypted device, I only found 1 tutorial about Arch Linux and the commands described didn't work on Debian.

I'm trying to abandon Ubuntu in favor of Debian however I find it really hard to setup a full encrypted device (except boot partition).
If you have any other solution to get Debian full encrypted I would be happy to try them.

It's 2 weeks I'm trying to setup Debian encrypted in this way on an USB device and I fail every single time.

Comment: Essentially what that GRUB error suggests is that you didn't install GRUB correctly. The partition it's configured to look at for it's stage2 files is incorrect. I don't know where you went wrong, but I recommend doing the install on your USB device but WITHOUT LUKS; just a plain un-encrypted install. Get that down. Only THEN add LUKS to the mix.

Comment: welcome to U&L , See the 3 steps here : https://www.linux.com/news/running-debian-gnulinux-encrypted-usb-drive to solve a similar problem